# Configure magit to use cygwin ssh with passphrase to push/pull from remote git repository

Tags: git, ssh, emacs, cygwin, magit

I followed the steps in https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows#git-gui--askpass
I installed ssh-agency and configure my `.emacs`  with

```el
(setenv "SSH_ASKPASS" "git-gui--askpass")
```

But without success, there is no prompt show up to ask for passphase.
I checked the configure of ssh-agency, it seems all right.

```
> Ssh Agency Gui Askpass Executable:
> D:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

Error message when I use magit to push is:

> Type C-h i to view popup manual, ? to describe an argument or action.
>   Saving file e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.ssh/agent.env... Wrote
>   e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.ssh/agent.env Running
>   D:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git push -v org
>   master:refs/heads/master [2 times] Could not read from remote
>   repository. ... [Hit $ to see buffer *magit-process: org_repos for
>   details]

Then I checked if existed the command `git-gui--askpass`, but there is no such kind of thing!

```
which git-gui--askpass
which: no git-gui--askpass in ...
```

Then I ran `D:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass` , it shows

```
Application initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Error in startup script: couldn't load file "/usr/bin/tk85.dll": No such file or directory
    while executing
"load /usr/bin/tk85.dll Tk"
    ("package ifneeded Tk 8.5.18" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Tk"
    (file "D:/cygwin64/usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass" line 8)
```

I think there is something wrong with my gui-git settings, I installed GitExtensions.

Comment: Are there any other details in the `magit-process` buffer?